# Typescript: Omit 1 field from type if all others are passed

Tags: typescript

Hi there i have a function called `createBreakpointValue` that takes an Object of arguments: `desktop, tablet, mobile, allElse`

The type-logic i am requiring is:
If all are passed (`desktop, tablet, mobile`), then `allElse` is irrelevant and should error if `allElse` is passed.

If some are passed (`mobile`), then `allElse` should be required or `desktop & tablet`.

What i currently have:

```js
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];

type Points =
  | {
      desktop: any;
      tablet: any;
      mobile: any;
      allElse?: never;
    }
  | {
      desktop?: any;
      tablet?: any;
      mobile?: any;
      allElse: any;
    };

const currentViewport: keyof Points = "desktop";
const createBreakpointValue = (points: Points): ValueOf<Points> => {
  if (currentViewport in points) {
    return points[currentViewport];
  } else {
    return points.allElse;
  }
};

// correct
createBreakpointValue({ allElse: 1 });

//correct
createBreakpointValue({ desktop: 1, tablet: 1, mobile: 1 });

// should highlight allElse as incorrect
createBreakpointValue({ allElse: 1, desktop: 1, mobile: 1, tablet: 1 });

// should highlight saying allElse or mobile should be provided
createBreakpointValue({ desktop: 1, tablet: 1 });
```

At the moment the typing is correct until i pass all correct arguments as well as allElse which i would expect to be highlighted saying something like "allElse is not valid here"

Sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-breeze-zlgws0?file=/src/index.ts

Comment: Why not solve this with an enum?

Comment: @ManfredWippel tell me more

Answer (score 1):

Th problem is that the value  passed in is still compatible with the last member of your union (the one with all members optional)

You could create a union where a member with all properties is incompatible iwth the union, by having the union expand with variants where at least one property must be  `undefined`:

```
type Points =
    | {
        desktop?: undefined
        tablet?: any
        mobile?: any
        allElse?: any
    }
    | {
        tablet?: undefined
        desktop?: any
        mobile?: any
        allElse?: any
    }
    | {
        mobile?: undefined
        desktop?: any
        tablet?: any
        allElse?: any
    }
    | {
        allElse?: undefined
        desktop?: any
        tablet?: any
        mobile?: any
    }
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACg9gSwHbAM5QLwCgq6gHygG8c8yATCVAa2DjAH4AuKAVyUoDNkJzSzcwAIYAjADYRgzKEKQh+AgLZwRCCdNnyBeIWLEBRMagga5CgL4LCJbYNESpLdlx59bUSjTqMWmhWWVVdV8zd10DIxMQrTxLMmt-PEC1KLYOCG4kXkTcT1p6UxjtYXFJQpyZPUNjcrI4vASwqsjpZwzXCrzvWtsShx7tZOCZUNisLABjOCRUYCgJgCcIIWAIACEloWowRBQANV1WaAwoAAod5DQWeEvUAEpozAA+YgUl4FYFpCgkVj0AQiwliwAHoQVB9AsFnAFpNNqsNsttrtgAcxEdTjYdM1jCwAIwAGgUXXo+KJZD6khYACZyUkVCkWABmInmO7jRbLBGbZGXNEYrG5Kj5MBkhSU4A0um4IYQZms9lwrnrHkXfaHCCYhThapyqCE4nC7xiin2KlQWlA9mclYqpFq1EarVkHWRE14Emi-XSqCy+VWoA)

You can probably also generate such a type using mapped types:

```
type NotAll<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: Partial<Record<P, undefined>> & Omit<T, P>
}[keyof T]
type Points = NotAll<{
    desktop?: any
    tablet?: any
    mobile?: any
    allElse?: any
}>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9sAggG2QHgCoD4oF4oDeAUFKVANoAKUAlgHZQDWEIcAZlBgLoBcUlAQwBOwGgPQAlCAGM4QgCZpKAGigBXOvIht6EeVhwAyKAHkAtjWCZVlLEQC+5Zqw7cioSPzj1gAZzywCCjoxGRQWr6MwHBgAPx8AnQgJGTAAgBGyBDA8VCJyWFmcOk0Wbn5KaTiyACiyL4Q5UkOdkSydL7AUNJCEALAEABCvQKMYN50wABq4mrQ+AAU4z6+fJQTfgCUCUl4OKFkvcBqQgx0aqgAhA5ERAD0d1A1QkJybSMDw31jGzPIcwsDlVUHUGnwAIzKSrhCCRaJgCFQsJpTLZPgAJiRZCKJSyfAAzFD7Jtbj0+p8Rj8fH8AUCYXCYojoSissAMVjSDjShACUSSe9yUNKctJjSIIDodVQTyoJDoREoozZRyoCy0VBMQ4SWT+kLviLprNxXSpfUZXKwgr4UzCsVubytUA)

Comment: Hey Titian, thanks for your reply :-) 

I've made a few little tweaks to my question with the new expected outcome.

Answer (score 0):

I like enums

```
enum ViewPort {
    desktop = 1 << 1,
    tablet = 1 << 2,
    mobile = 1 << 3,    
    allElse = desktop | tablet | mobile
}

const currentViewport: ViewPort = ViewPort.desktop;
const createBreakpointValue = (points: ViewPort) => {
        return (points & currentViewport) === currentViewport;
};
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! so i think maybe i havent explained enough. 

The createBreakpointValue function takes arguments as an object. 

And whatever the current value of currentViewport is, it returns the points[currentViewport] that way i can have different values for different screen widths. i.e imagine a scenario where i want diferent font sizes for mob, tablet & desktop.

Comment: @FrancisLeigh I saw your solution and I think you can achieve this by using an enum.